# C# does not implement inherited abstract member

Tags: c#

I have searched very much about this question. There are many ways which are explained but they have not been usable for me.

I have this class:

```
public class ArcHydro : Oatc.OpenMI.Sdk.Backbone.LinkableComponent
{
   public void Initialize(Argument[] properties)
        {
            _timeStamps = new ArrayList();
            _culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
            _links = new Hashtable();
            readArcHydro();
        }
}
```

Which inherits this class

```
namespace Oatc.OpenMI.Sdk.Backbone
{
    public abstract void Initialize(IArgument[] properties);
}
```

The error is

```
`'CUAHSI.OpenMI.ArcHydro' does not implement inherited abstract member 
'Oatc.OpenMI.Sdk.Backbone.LinkableComponent.Initialize(OpenMI.Standard.IArgument`[])'`
```

How can I solve it?
I used override before class but the error remains.

Comment: Well your method has a parameter type of `Argument[]`, and the abstract method has a parameter type of `IArgument[]`. They don't have the same signature, so you're not implementing the abstract method. You also need the `override` modifier - if you try applying that at the moment, it'll tell you that it can't find the method you're trying to override, due to the parameter type problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems. You should be implementing:

```
public abstract void Initialize(IArgument[] properties);
```

but you're implementing:

```
public void Initialize(Argument[] properties);
// --------------------^ Notice the missing 'I'.
```

Secondly, you're missing the `override` keyword. So your class should look like this:

```
public class ArcHydro : Oatc.OpenMI.Sdk.Backbone.LinkableComponent
{
    public override void Initialize(IArgument[] properties)
    {
        _timeStamps = new ArrayList();
        _culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
        _links = new Hashtable();
        readArcHydro();
    }
}
```

Comment: third problem, why Initialize method is inside namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation function should have the "override" keyword, and the same arguments.

```
public override void Initialize(IArgument[] properties)
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the implemented method should be exactly the same as the abstract one. Therefore you should have it like this:

```
public override void Initialize(IArgument[] properties)
{
...
}
```

Please pay attention that your input arguments should be from type IArgument[] which you have mentioned in your abstract class and remember to mark it as override

Follow the example on [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract)